# Locate specific pixel from left and right view in the disparity map

Tags: c++, opencv, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping, stereoscopy

I am trying to find a way to extract the depth of a specific pixel present in the left and right view that generate the disparity map.

Let's say I have two perfectly rectified left and right view, I am able to automatically recognize through the chessboard pattern the coordinates of all the corners of the chessboard in both views. Out of all the corners, let's say I want to consider only the bottom left. So now I have the 2D coordinates of the bottom left coordinate in the right and left view, however for my project I need also its depth which I could extract from the disparity map.

How can I find the exact pixel to which that corner corresponds to in the disparity map, having just the 2D coordinates of that same corner in the left and right view?

I am using OpenCV and C++ if that is useful.